# java, "do this if passes then do this"

Tags: java, netbeans

please bear with me as im a beginner,

the code is
    extract:

```
'CalcCost calculate = new CalcCost();  '
 String key = stockNofive.getText(); 
 String quantityTxt = quantityfive.getText();
 int QuantityInt = Integer.parseInt(quantityTxt);            
 calculate.String(key, quantityTxt); // sending key and quantity to another class for user input check
 calculate.Jlabel(stockJLBfive, quantityJLBfive); // sending jlabel for colour change if any error found

error.Colour();// recieve error value if any, if there is  do not carry on,

//if error passes then do the following
        calculate.setKey(key);
        calculate.setQuantity(QuantityInt);
        double cost = calculate.calculateBill();
        information.append("\n\nTotal cost: £" + pounds.format(cost));
        ............
        ........
```

this is the error checking class

```
try {
        if (key.equals("")) {
            StockJLb.setText("<html><span style=\"color: red;\">Enter stock number</span></html>");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "One or more fields missing");
            return StockJLb;

        }
        if (QuantityStr.equals("")) {
            QuantityJLb.setText("<html><span style=\"color: red;\">Enter quantity</span></html>");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "One or more fields blank");
            return QuantityJLb;
        }

    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        QuantityJLb.setText("<html><span style=\"color: red;\">Enter quantity</span></html>");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "'" + QuantityStr + "' is not a number");
       error= true;
        return QuantityJLb;
    }
```

please reply back if need more code, or anything else, been  stuck on this for 2 weeks now.
im sorry if still unlclear i put notes in the code to help, 
what i want to code is if there is an error dont carry on do the calculation, if there isnt and it passes the error checking do the calculation, ive tried if statments, and tried adding boolean , but still cant figure it out,

Comment: maybe you can put some more code to understand well the context and what you want to do, please.

Comment: what does it mean for the error to pass?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, from what I see I would just recommend you to read about try/catch blocks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're not looking for an `if` statement are you?

```
if(error.Colour() == /*insert value to check here*/)
{
    calculate.setKey(key);
    calculate.setQuantity(QuantityInt);
    double cost = calculate.calculateBill();
    information.append("\n\nTotal cost: £" + pounds.format(cost));
}
```

Comment: ive tried     if    statments but dont knoe the conditions, to use

Comment: @user2158735 that's why I asked you before, `what does it mean for the error to pass?`

Comment: it mean not to carry on with the code, until user types in something valid, is this what you ment?

Comment: @user2158735 how would you know whether or not the user had typed something valid?

Comment: that is why there a class called calcCost, this is where it checks if user typed in something valid, if user types incorrectly the JLabel color changes and MessageDialog comes up, the JLabel colour is sent to the class1 so on the GUI if notifies this is where the error is,

Answer (score 0):

`error.Colour();// return the error value`

(SO then save it into a variable or use it in an if condition!)

```
if (error.Colour() == valueOfError) {
            calculate.setKey(key);
            calculate.setQuantity(QuantityInt);
            double cost = calculate.calculateBill();
            information.append("\n\nTotal cost: £" + pounds.format(cost));
            ............
            ........
} else {
//It is success
}
```

Comment: the      'calculate.setKey(key);
            calculate.setQuantity(QuantityInt);
            double cost = calculate.calculateBill();
            information.append("\n\nTotal cost: £" + pounds.format(cost));
            ............
            ........ 'is the success

Comment: it returns a Jlabel value, also what would 'valueOfError' be?

Comment: so, it returns a JLabel component or the text of your label ? I mean the .getText() method of your label? The valueError depends on what you're expecting. What are the requirements of your application? When it should be error and when it should be success?

Comment: it changes the colour of the JLabel, which has text in it, the .getText(), is getting user input via TextField                            `JTextField stockNo = new JTextField(7);                       JLabel quantityJLBfive = new JLabel ("enter Quantity");
JLabel stockJLBfive = new JLabel ("enter stock number");` its defualt is black what the error checking class does is return the JLabel colour red, if its red i want the user to type in again until its something valid, when its black its a sucess, hopefully this make sense

Answer (score 0):

Since it's only small portion of code it's little difficult to get entire picture but whatever I understood you want to execute lines after `calculate.setKey(key);` based on a condition. Am I correct?

You can always store the value of `error.Colour()` into some variable i.e. Not sure what it returns, I am assuming it is of type String.

`String colourErrorValue = error.Colour();// return the error value`

Then you can check the value to make sure it does not have any error. i.e.

```
//if error passes then do the following
if(colourErrorValue.equals("NO ERROR VALUE") { // I don't know what is no error scenario in                              
                                             //your case but just assuming the string
        calculate.setKey(key);
        calculate.setQuantity(QuantityInt);
        double cost = calculate.calculateBill();
        information.append("\n\nTotal cost: £" + pounds.format(cost));
        ............
        ........
}
```

If the `error.Colour()` method throws a exception or error then you just need to wrap the code around try and catch.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the return value is a change in colour of JLabel,